# Lumen (Laravel) include library & use class in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a question! I have a library, whenever I need to call, I'll include it into & `new Class()` like the link below.

Now, I want to include it to use with Lumen framework & call usually inton Controller, then how to register service, class in Lumen to make it comfortable so that when needing, just call `new FileMaker();`

http://laravel.io/bin/E3d9x

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [Service Provider](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/providers#registering-providers). Instead of including files in your Controllers, and then new'ing up instances of a class it is better to register the class within a service provider and then resolve the object out of the [IoC container](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/container).

An example of how you can register a provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('Full\Vendor\Namespace\FileMaker', function($app)     {
        return new FileMaker('someparameters');
    });
}
```

Doing it this way means that you can inject dependencies into your Controllers and Laravel, or Lumen in this case will automatically resolve the object without you needing to instantiate the object.

For example, in your controller:

```
public function someControllerMethod(FileMaker $filemaker)
{
    // The $filemaker instance is available to use
}
```

Comment: Error: Class App\Http\Controllers\FileMaker does not exist :(

Comment: @HieuTran So you accepted the answer and it didn't work for you?

Comment: That error wouldn't be the result of the code I provided. It'd be because his class either doesn't exist in the namespace he declared, the class isn't imported, autoloading hasn't been set up, or something else along those lines.